# Clear focus of BottomSheetDialog

Tags: java, android

I have a ListView in my layout. I have attached `onItemClickListener` for ListView to listen for item clicks. Whenever I will click on the item of it, a `BottomSheetDialog` will inflate. The problem is, that I want the content outside bottomsheetdialog to be clickable and scrollable. Whenever I inflate BottomSheetDialog, the content outside it becomes unresponsive. It doesn't respond to clicks, scroll etc. How can I make the content outside it to still be clickable and scrollable?